# How to empty all select field value if either day, month or year default value is selected in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, advanced-custom-fields

Please view my code below, i am trying to clear all select field values if either **day, month or year** default value is selected and if default value is not selected then value picked should be shown and update the hidden input field but for some reason it doesn't.

```js
$('.date-dropdowns').on('change', '.day,.month,.year', function() {
  var d = $(this).parent().find('.day').val();
  var m = $(this).parent().find('.month').val();
  var y = $(this).parent().find('.year').val();
  var dmy = d + '/' + m + '/' + y;
  

  if(d === "" || m === "" || y === ""){
   $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val('');
   $(this).parent().find('select').prop('selectedIndex',0);
  }else{
   $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val(dmy);
  }
  
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-dropdowns">
<input type="hidden" id="acf-field_5a7cbdad4e6af-0-field_5a7b65d4e90ca-field_5a7b665f779f4" name="acf[field_5a7cbdad4e6af][0][field_5a7b65d4e90ca][field_5a7b665f779f4]" value="" required="required">
<select class="day" name="date_[day]">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="01">1st</option>
    <option value="02">2nd</option>
    <option value="03">3rd</option>
    <option value="04">4th</option>
</select>
<select class="month" name="date_[month]">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
<select class="year" name="date_[year]">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you need the IF statement? It is the reason for the select to keep having no selected option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your checking condition indicated that if either year, month or day are default, all values are reset to default. This is always true as user can only change one at a time, the others must be default at that time. You may want to check only the one the user selected is default or not.

```js
$('.date-dropdowns').on('change', '.day,.month,.year', function() {
  var d = $(this).parent().find('.day').val();
  var m = $(this).parent().find('.month').val();
  var y = $(this).parent().find('.year').val();
  var dmy = d + '/' + m + '/' + y;


  if ($(this).val() === '') {
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val('');
    $(this).parent().find('select').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  } else {
    $(this).parent().find('input[type=hidden]').val(dmy);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="date-dropdowns">
  <input type="hidden" id="acf-field_5a7cbdad4e6af-0-field_5a7b65d4e90ca-field_5a7b665f779f4" name="acf[field_5a7cbdad4e6af][0][field_5a7b65d4e90ca][field_5a7b665f779f4]" value="" required="required">
  <select class="day" name="date_[day]">
    <option value="">Day</option>
    <option value="01">1st</option>
    <option value="02">2nd</option>
    <option value="03">3rd</option>
    <option value="04">4th</option>
  </select>
  <select class="month" name="date_[month]">
    <option value="">Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
  </select>
  <select class="year" name="date_[year]">
    <option value="">Year</option>
    <option value="2018">2018</option>
    <option value="2017">2017</option>
    <option value="2016">2016</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
    <option value="2014">2014</option>
    <option value="2013">2013</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: So simple yet i spent hours trying to figure it out :). Thank you.